# I'm trying to use a method to print another method

Tags: java, methods

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello and welcome! Please enter the following: ");

    String q = null, s = "nul";
    userName(q);
    userGender(s);

    print(userName(q));
    print(userGender(s)); // how to achieve something like this?
}

public static void userName(String x) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    String n = sc.nextLine();
}

public static void userGender(String y) {
    Scanner sd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter Gender: ");
    String v = sd.next().toString();
}

public static void print(String a) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

So I was trying to make it so that a method would be used to print another method after they were done executing but I couldn't get the desired result and it gave an error.

Comment: "but I couldn't get the desired result and it gave an error" - Are you expecting us to guess what the desired result and the *error* are?

Comment: Well, if you try to print the return value of a method that does not return anything, it won't give you the *desired result*...

Comment: Usually, when I hear "print another method" all I can think of are either printing source code of some other method, or printing results of reflection over that "other" method. I'm guessing this is neither: but what is it? What is your question? What did you want to happen? What happened instead? What is the error, if any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method needs to return something. You are declaring your method like this: `public static void  userGender(String y)` the `void` means that your method won't return anything. But since you want that the method returns a `String` you need to tell this in the method signature.

Your code could look like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello and welcome! Please enter the following: ");
    print(userName());
    print(userGender()); 
  }

  public static String userName() {
    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)){ // this is try resource see which will close your resource once you are done in the try block see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html
      System.out.print("Enter name: ");
      return sc.next();
    }
  }

  public static String userGender() {
    try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
      System.out.print("Enter Gender: ");
      return sc.next();
    }
  }

  public static void print(String a) {
    System.out.println(a);
  }
```

You don't need to use `toString()` since the next returns already a String. Also you can use the same variable name in different methods. And really important you need to close the Scanner again, otherwise it will consume endless resources.

Answer (score 1):

The method print works fine, it takes a String and return nothing

```
public static void print(String a)
{
    System.out.println(a);

}
```

However, your method userGender and userName returns nothing, so when you are feeding print with a method that isn't returning a string, it will produce an compile-time error. You want to do something similar to:

```
public static String  userGender(String y){
     Scanner sd = new Scanner(System.in); 
     System.out.print("Enter Gender: ");
     return sd.next().toString(); 
}
```

I haven't tested it, as your logic is unclear to me, but this is probably why your IDE is complaining.

Answer (score 0):

Like @reebow and @Kerry Gougeon both pointed out that your method is looking to return something so you make it  `public static String userName()` or `public static String userName(String s)`.

If you're wanting to user `Scanner` then you're going to have to declare  `Scanner` globally, otherwise it will throw a `NoSuchElementExcpetion`

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello and welcome! Please enter the following: ");
    print(userName());
    print(userGender()); 
}

public static String userName() {
    System.out.print("Enter name: ");
    return sc.next();
}

public static String userGender() {
    System.out.print("Enter Gender: ");
    return sc.next();
}

public static void print(String a) {
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

If you're not using `Scanner` then you can just return the `String` that you passed to the method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("Hello and welcome! Please enter the following: ");
      String a = null, b ="nul";
      print(userName(a));
      print(userGender(b)); 
  }

  public static String userName(String a) {
      System.out.print("Enter name: ");
      return a;
  }

  public static String userGender(String b) {
      System.out.print("Enter Gender: ");
      return b;
  }

  public static void print(String a) {
      System.out.println(a);
  }
```